# Using an Alias to restart SQL sequence with

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence

I'd like to make it so, that a sequence starts with the max value(+1) of a certain column. This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT MAX(customer_number)+1 AS HighestCustomerNumberPlusOne FROM organisation;

CREATE SEQUENCE customer_number_sequence
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE customer_number_sequence RESTART WITH HighestCustomerNumberPlusOne;
```

And I get the error:

```
Error: Incorrect syntax near 'HighestCustomerNumberPlusOne'.
SQLState:  S0001
ErrorCode: 102
```

What is the correct syntax? I'm using SQL Server 2012 but would prefer just generic SQL if it's possible, since the T-SQL is harder than learning Chinese.

Comment: Yes that answered my question. Thank you. Didn't find duplicate because of the wording of the question.

Answer (score 1):

[`ALTER SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878572.aspx) syntax accepts only constants in the `RESTART WITH` clause.

So, you'll have to save the result of your query into a variable; construct a string with `ALTER SEQUENCE` SQL command and embed the value of the variable in the SQL text, then execute it as dynamic SQL using `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`.

But, normally there is no need to reset the sequence.

What do you **really** need?